# Mathpartir: How to insert "\\" between entries with macro?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, paragraphs, arguments

I'm using a tool to generate large amounts of LaTeX, which contain inference rules that I'm typesetting using [mathpartir](http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/macros/latex/contrib/mathpartir/mathpartir.pdf).

Below, I've got a MWE that's very similar to the code I've got generated. What I'd like to do is redefine it as `\renewcommand{\ottpremise}[1]{#1\\}`, to separate each of the premises in mathpartir. This allows it to decide where to add linebreaks, which is the main feature I'm going after.

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Argument of \\ has an extra }.
```

I think the problem might have something to do with the fact that there's an extra `\\` left over after the last premise.

What is causing this error? Is there a way to nicely add `\\` between my premises, given that each is wrapped in a call to `\ottpremise`? Is it necessary/possible to avoid the extra `\\` at the end?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}


\newcommand{\ottdefntstep}[1]{
    \begin{ottdefnblock}[#1]{
    $\Gamma  \mid  \Theta  \vdash  \mathit{T}  \leadsto  \mathit{T'}$
    }{}
\ottusedrule{\ottdruleTStepAssoc{}}
\end{ottdefnblock}
}

\newcommand{\ottdruleTStepAssoc}[1]{\ottdrule[#1]{%
\ottpremise{\Gamma  \mid  \Theta  \Vdash  \tau  :  \mathit{D}  \langle  \tau_{{\mathrm{1}}}  , \, .. \, ,  \tau_{\mathit{n}}  {;}  \mathit{X}  \mapsto  \tau'  \rangle}%
\ottpremise{\Gamma  \mid  \Theta  \vdash  (   [  \tau'  /   \mathit{X} _ \mathit{D}   ]   )  \leadsto  \mathit{T'}}%
}{
\Gamma  \mid  \Theta  \vdash  \mathit{T}  \leadsto  \mathit{T'}}{%
{TStepAssoc}{}%
}}

\newcommand{\ottusedrule}[1]{#1\and}

\newcommand{\ottdrule}[4][]{{\inferrule[#4]{TODO #2 TODO}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\ottpremise}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{ottdefnblock}[3][]
{
    \begin{mathpar}
        }
        {
    \end{mathpar}
}

\ottdefntstep{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't add the \\ within the \inferrule call? So you'd get {TODO \\ #2 \\ TODO} indeed avoiding an "empty" \\

Comment: @remco the idea is that #2 is a sequence of premises, and i want all of them separated by //

Comment: You can't, sorry: `mathpartir` needst to *see* ``\\`` in order to separate the premises; if you hide it in a macro, it will not work.

Comment: Then, if you can only modify the \ottpremise command, I don't think what you want is possible: your `\ottpremise` code would have to figure out if the current `\ottpremise' is the last in a series.

Comment: @egreg that would explain why a quick test with xparse didn't work...